# Azure AD SSO in ASP.NET - How to update token silently?

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a quite simple ASP.NET project that has the Azure AD Authentication installed.
It uses the CookieAuthentication by default and uses the Azure AD SSO to login.

So what I can't understand is that if I login and left the page opened for 1 hour - which is the Azure AD access token expiration time, it just stops working.

To avoid this, I tried to update the access token silently before it is expired but failed.
Not even sure why the app stops working as it's using Cookie for authorization and it uses the Azure AD login only for Authentication.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = (context) =>
        {
            var threshold = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(55);

            if (context.Properties.ExpiresUtc < threshold)
            {
                var authManager = context.OwinContext.Authentication;

                string signedInUserID = context.Identity.FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                if (authContext == null)
                    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));

                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                try
                {
                    var result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, clientId).Result;
                }
                catch (AggregateException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException))
                    {
                        var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, credential).Result;
                    }
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the ADALTokenCache.

```
public class ADALTokenCache : TokenCache
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private string userId;
        private UserTokenCache Cache;

        public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
        {
            // Associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            userId = signedInUserId;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
            // Look up the entry in the database
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            // Place the entry in memory
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache"));
        }

        // Clean up the database
        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            var cacheEntry = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            db.UserTokenCacheList.Remove(cacheEntry);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Notification raised before ADAL accesses the cache.
        // This is your chance to update the in-memory copy from the DB, if the in-memory version is stale
        void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            if (Cache == null)
            {
                // First time access
                Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            }
            else
            {
                // Retrieve last write from the DB
                var status = from e in db.UserTokenCacheList
                             where (e.webUserUniqueId == userId)
                select new
                {
                    LastWrite = e.LastWrite
                };

                // If the in-memory copy is older than the persistent copy
                if (status.First().LastWrite > Cache.LastWrite)
                {
                    // Read from from storage, update in-memory copy
                    Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
                }
            }
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
        }

        // Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
        // If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
        void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // If state changed
            if (this.HasStateChanged)
            {
                Cache = new UserTokenCache
                {
                    webUserUniqueId = userId,
                    cacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.Serialize(), "ADALCache"),
                    LastWrite = DateTime.Now
                };
                // Update the DB and the lastwrite
                db.Entry(Cache).State = Cache.UserTokenCacheId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                this.HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }

        void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // If you want to ensure that no concurrent write take place, use this notification to place a lock on the entry
            var t = args;
        }

        public override void DeleteItem(TokenCacheItem item)
        {
            base.DeleteItem(item);
        }
    }
```

This is what I tried, but not working.
Would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a suggestion, use async and await in that handler. Using .Result can cause various "fun" bugs. Specify the handler as `async (context) =>` and use `await` before the Async function calls. You can then remove the `return Task.FromResult()`

Comment: Thanks, @juunas. I tried async/await, but got the same error. The strange thing is that the AcquireTokenSilentAsync and AcquireTokenAsync functions are working without error before the token expires, but it stops working after the token expires.

Comment: Sounds like your token cache is then not working as it should. Could you share your `ADALTokenCache`?

Comment: I added the TokenCache code to the question. Actually it's the default ADALTokenCache that was created by default.